# Help me to find C wire

Tags: thermostat-c-wire

[image]

GV1 - ZONE 1 VALVE
GV2 - ZONE 2 VALVE
Y1 - YELLOW WIRE 1
Y2 - YELLOW WIRE 2
R1 - RED WIRE 1
R2- RED WIRE 2

TT1 - ZONE 1 THERMOSTAT
TT2 - ZONE 2 THERMOSTAT 
R RED WIRE
W WHITE WIRE
B BLUE WIRE

BOILER TX TRANSFORMER
R RED WIRE
B BLUE WIRE
G GREEN WIRE
W WHITE WIRE

We recently replaced old water boiler heater with new one(williamson) and I took the opportunity to fish new thermostat cable as well(replaced 2 conductor with 5). But my plumber is saying, I still can't use new Wi-Fi thermostat with it and it won't be efficient. I assuming that we wish to finish this job and move on to next one. So can someone please help me to find C wire for Honeywell thermostat. I have attached the current wiring picture with post. If you need any additional details please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Here are few more pictures.

[image]

In picture you can see green and blue coming to gas control. Yellow is not used and looped back, while white and red is going to outside transformer which is in other side connected to emergency switch.

Can't upload anymore pics to the post. :(

Wiring harness from right side
TSTAT
DAMPER

Update#3
Boiler make and model
http://www.williamson-thermoflo.com/sites/default/files/field-file/gwa_manual.pdf
 model GWA 175
Valve - Honeywell make

[image]

Comment: Can you post detailed photos of the wiring at the boiler please?

Comment: BTW: post links to the pics and we can edit them in

Comment: What's the make and model of the boiler?  Can you post the schematic from the boiler (should be inside the access panel)? What's the make and model of the zone valves?

Comment: From what I can tell, you've either not shown us the `C` wire, or haven't provided enough information about the system for us to be sure which wire would be `C`.

Comment: What model Honeywell thermostat are you trying to install?

Comment: Here is Honeywell Thermostat I have purchased. Honeywell RTH6580WF Wi-Fi 7-Day Programmable Thermostat http://yourhome.honeywell.com/en/products/thermostat/wi-fi-7-day-programmable-thermostat-rth6580wf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be in luck, but it depends on how the Honeywell thermostat works.  I know Ecobee3 lets you power the thermostat using the `Rc` and `C` terminals, but I'm not sure if Honeywell does the same. However, this solution might still work, even if the Honeywell is not the same as an EcoBee3.

If you look at the documentation for the boiler, you'll see this.

> [image: Feild wiring connections for boiler]

Which shows that the boiler exposes additional wiring, that's intended specifically for powering a thermostat.

You can see these two wires in the photo of your boiler.

> [image: Boiler photo]

If the Honeywell can be powered using `Rc` and `C`, then here's what you'll have to do.

1. Install an 18 AWG (at least) 2-wire (at least) cable between the boiler and the thermostat(s).
2. Connect one of the wires to the wire labeled `R` in the boiler (as highlighted above).
3. Connect the other wire to the wire labeled `C` in the boiler (as highlighted above).
4. At the thermostat, remove the jumper between `R` and `Rc`.
5. Connect the wire that is connected to the `R` wire in the boiler, to the `Rc` terminal on the thermostat base.
6. Connect the wire that is connected to the `C` wire in the boiler, to the `C` terminal on the thermostat base.
7. Connect the other thermostat wires as they were on the old thermostat.

---

If the Honeywell thermostat cannot be powered using `Rc` and `C`, then you may still be able to get it working.  Follow the same procedure as above, but do not connect the wire between the `R` wire in the boiler and the `Rc` terminal at the thermostat. Also, leave the jumper in place between `R` and `Rc`.  This may or may not work, depending on how the system is currently wired.

Comment: This looks promising. I will follow your instructions and update the thread by weekend. Thank you very much for your detailed analysis!

Comment: Any idea what should be voltage between R and C wire? Before I connect these two to stat, I want to make sure there is enough voltage to power up stat. Thanks

Comment: @nil 24 volts. But it will more likely measure around 27-28 volts with no load.

Comment: You sir, are brilliant! The technician who said it can't be done, you proved him wrong. :) I have connected one of the zone tstat as per your suggestion. It booted up fine and working flawlessly. Now if I have to connect other zone tstat, can I jump second tstat wires at same junction point? I have 2 more additional zone where I am planning to use similar made tstat. Thand!

Comment: @nil you can add more thermostats, however, you'll have been careful not to overload the transformer.   I'm not sure how much current smart thermostats draw, but you'll want to check that out before adding more.  Otherwise, you'll have to upgrade the transformer.

Comment: No problem, I will check with manufacturer. Thanks!